# Can't see the axis to scale objects

Tags: modeling

[image]

I don't really know what happened before but usually, it would have the 3 axis there so you can edit the cube for me as in the picture up top it isn't there. How can I get it back?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You have unchecked Gizmo overlays:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know that could be a possibility.